# What is the name of this instrument with 2 strings?

Tags: string-instruments

[image]

Hi,
I bought this instrument in Kabul and the seller told me it was a dutar. But now that I'm looking at some pictures online, it looks different. Can you tell me what it's called?
Thanks.

Edit:
I'm going to add a couple of more pictures.
The length is about 1 meter and it weighs around 700gr. The back is closed and it is wooden except the surface which looks like some sort of skin. The strings are nylon.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "dutar" is literally "du  - tar" meaning "two  -  strings" in... I wanna say Persian languages?  Well, "du" is proto-indo European two anyway: think *deux, dos, dois dozen*

Comment: The dutar is a type of lute, with a lute-shaped wooden body. Your picture looks more like a two-stringed banjo, though we can't see if the instrument has a back or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because instrument identification questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's supposed to be a [ghichak](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1GbRKs5frU), which can optionally have a [skin face](http://www.orientbazar.eu/musikinstrument-afghanistan-ghichak-17-2-ghg-copy.html) or be a solid box.

But checking Google image search, apparently ghichaks having the pegs be on the front like that is not conventional - ghichaks have sideways pegs – and possibly unheard of.  I think of vertical pegs being more conventional of African rather than Asian instruments, though I wouldn't swear to it; a quick google search of African banjos shows vertical pegs, but usually coming in from the back.

Also, a ghichak is supposed to have more than that one has of a stick pointing out of the bottom, which is functional – like the foot of a cello.  By resting the instrument on that point, it gets the body up off the floor or the player's lap, so the box can resonate freely.

Ghichaks come in a wide variety of body shapes, the most famous being the double-bowl, but, really, [any box on a stick will do](http://thewanderingscot.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Ghaychak.jpg).

Yours is awfully pretty, but it seems pretty odd.  If it is supposed to be a ghichak, perhaps it is meant as a display-only item.

P.S. Also see [gusle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gusle) (Serbian) which at least has vertical pins, though coming in from the back, and [morin khuur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morin_khuur) (Mongolian).

Answer (score 1):

That probably is indeed a dutar, due to the number of strings. Its peculiar shape mirrors a variation found in the [tambur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_tambur). There are two kinds, the plucked mızraplı tambur, which has a fully wooden body and a heavily rounded back; and the bowed [yaylı tambur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yayl%C4%B1_tambur), which has a skin head and a shallow back, like your instrument. So, it looks like you found a "yaylı dutar".